Kernel Density Estimation and Nadaraya Watson Estimator reference
I am looking for a reference that is on kernel density estimators with the following results:
Let $(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{p} \times \mathbb{R}$ are i.i.d. and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=m(x)$. Let $\hat{p}(x)=\frac{1}{n h_{n}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n K(\frac{x-X_i}{h_n})$ and $\hat{m}(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{n h_{n}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_iK(\frac{x-X_i}{h_n})}{\hat{p}(x)}$. If $K$ is an (even) biased-reducing kernel, say $\int K(u)u^{j}du=0$ for all $j<m$:
I am looking for the full derivation of the bounds $\int\limits \mathbb{E}[\left\{\hat{m}(x)-m(x)\right\}^2]dx$ and $\int \mathbb{E}[\left\{\hat{p}(x)-p(x)\right\}^2]dx$.
I have looked at Van Der Vaart and other books, they do not seem to give a full treatment higher than the one dimensional case.
